# Decomposition of Gaussian spaces with respect to covariance function

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian

Let $K(t,s):T^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a kernel symmetric and type positive (for every $n$ $\sum^n_{i,j}u_iu_jK(t_i,t_j) \geq 0$ and $(u_1,\dots,u_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$) where $T$ is any set. Thus, it is possible get a suitable probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F},P$) and a Gaussian process $(X_t)_{t \in D}:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with values in $\mathcal{H}$ (a closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P$) of Gaussian process with mean 0) and $K$ is the covariance function of $X_t$. I know that if I can write $X_t = Z^{1}_t + Z^2_t$ where $Z^{1}_t$ and $ Z^2_t$ are independent centered Gaussian processes then 
$$K(t,s) = K_1(t,s) + K_2(t,s),$$ 
where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the covariance function of $Z^{1}_t$ and  $Z^2_t$ respectively. I'm asking for a converse of it: If I have $K(t,s) = K_1(t,s) + K_2(t,s)$, then I can get $Z^{1}_t$ and $ Z^2_t$ independent centered Gaussian processes. Thanks for any help.